# Как прочесть три последние символа?

Tags: c++, c

Помогите решить задачу, нужно прочесть последние 3 символа с файла. Пример: файл.тхт содержит тест "`1234567890..............54227788`". Нужно вывести на экран `788`.

Comment: что не получается? на чем застряли?

Comment: не умею пользоваться функцией fseek()

Comment: Прочитайте наконец-то <a href=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/>справку</a>.

Answer (score 3):

1. Делаете fseek на конец файла.
2. Считываете последние три байта.
3. Выводите на экран
4. PROFIT

Случай с файлами < 3 байта рассмотреть отдельно; обратить внимание, что файлы могут быть оооооочень большие (>2GB или >4GB), подумать как с ними работать.

Comment: программа нужна для файла размера 1 Мб например